# Php dynamic forms while loop

Tags: php, html

**This is my dynamic form**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="thebox" value="selected<?php echo"$x"; ?>"/>
 </td>

<td>
<input type="text" class="thebox" name="id<?php echo"$x"; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['member_id']; ?>" />
 </td>

 <td>
<input type="text" class="thebox" name="fn<?php echo"$x"; ?>" value=" <?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>"/>
</td>

 <td>
 <input type="text" class="thebox" name="ln<?php echo"$x"; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>"/>
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type="text" class="thebox" name="sd<?php echo"$x"; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['start_date']; ?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<?php 
$x++;
endwhile;
                ?>
 <tr align="center">
<td>
 </td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="delmem" class="myButton" value="Delete member "/>
 </td>

</tr>    
</table>
</form>
 </div>
```

I am trying to get the selected check box variables only. I have tried everything. I know I am a php noob someone help me please.  How can I retrieve the selected check box attributes?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['delmem']))
{

$i = 1;
while($i <=  $_SESSION['stuff'])
{
$a = $_POST["fn"."$i"]."<br />";            
echo  $a;
$i++;

if(isset($_POST["selected"."$i"]))
{
echo $_POST["$fn"."$i"]."<br />";
echo $_POST["$ln"."$i"];                                
}

}

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you made mistake in post Variable

$_POST["$fn"."$i"] to  $_POST["fn"."$i"]

```
if(isset($_POST["selected"."$i"]))  
{
  echo $_POST["$fn"."$i"]."<br />";
  echo $_POST["$ln"."$i"];                                
}
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST["selected"."$i"])) 
{
  echo $_POST["fn"."$i"]."<br />";
  echo $_POST["ln"."$i"];                                
}
```

Comment: If this is fixed by my solution then please accept my answer , thanks